# Stored procedure not working properly via EXECUTE

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, stored-procedures, sql-update

I have the following stored procedure but it's not working properly. if call the procedure it gives a correct value but not updated the next value.

```sql
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `GetCommonSequenceReferenceData`;
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetCommonSequenceReferenceData`(
    IN refData JSON
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE sequ_id BIGINT;
    DECLARE sequ_next_id BIGINT;

        SELECT *
        FROM COMMON_SEQ_REF_TB
        WHERE seq_type = refData ->> "$.seq_type";

        SET sequ_id = (SELECT seq_id
                       FROM COMMON_SEQ_REF_TB
                           WHERE seq_type = refData ->> "$.seq_type");
        SET sequ_next_id = (SELECT next_id
                            FROM COMMON_SEQ_REF_TB
                                WHERE seq_type = refData ->> "$.seq_type");

        IF (sequ_id IS NULL) THEN
            SET sequ_next_id = 1;
            INSERT INTO COMMON_SEQ_REF_TB (seq_type, next_id, created_at, updated_at)
            VALUES (refData ->> "$.seq_type", sequ_next_id,
                    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());

        ELSE

            SET sequ_next_id = sequ_next_id + 1;

            -- UPDATE START
            UPDATE COMMON_SEQ_REF_TB
            SET next_id    = sequ_next_id,
                updated_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
            WHERE  seq_type = refData ->> "$.seq_type";
        END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Provide a sample - CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, some CALL stmts and desired data state after each stmt - which allows to reproduce your problem.

Comment: *via EXECUTE* What do you mean? Whee you use this EXECUTE and how it looks like - in details.

Comment: By design it doesn't seem to be possible: `refData ->> "$.seq_type"` (`refData` local variable). Is the `sequ_id` column auto-incremental?. I can't reproduce the problem with `sequ_id` being auto-incremental, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ehu8nfj_).